# Google voice recognizer taking alphanumeric\integers as voice inputs

Tags: android, input, numeric, voice-recognition, alphanumeric

I am working on a voice recognition application that uses Google voice recognizer.
I need the user to enter some alphanumeric code that it as it is processes rather getting matching words with confidence scores. 
I also need the user to provide numbers as voice inputs to select items in the list.
However, it converts it to a string or matching words.

**Below is my code for the Recognizer**

```
intentVoice = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intentVoice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);        
            intentVoice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ENGLISH);
        intentVoice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "voice.recognition.test");
        intentVoice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 15);
        sr.startListening(intentVoice);
```

Any help or suggestions will be very helpful.
Thank you!